# iOS: How to check if a variable has changed his value in another ViewController in a dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I would like to know how to check if a value changed in another ViewController that is running in background. I have that code in that Viewcontroller that is downloading in background, and it puts me the **isSyncAutoOnGoing** to **NO** when the download is finished.

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    BOOL isSyncAutoOnGoing;
}

  - (void) sync:(id) sender
    {
    isSyncAutoOnGoing = YES;
           dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NUL

L);
                dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

                    // do our long running process here
                    ListOfValueSync * lovSync = [[ListOfValueSync alloc] init];

                    // Synchronization
                    BOOL ret = [lovSync getAllListOfValueAll];

                    // do any UI stuff on the main UI thread
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [spinner stopAnimating];
                        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
                        isSyncAutoOnGoing = NO;
                        NSLog(isSyncAutoOnGoing ? @"sync Yes" : @"sync No");
                        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                        {
                            self.loginField.text = @"";
                            (!ret) ? [self alertStatus:@"Can not synchronize" :@"Sync Failed!" :0] : [self alertStatus:@"Synchronization OK" :@"Sync OK" :0];
                            [sender setEnabled:TRUE];
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
    }
```

Here is the FormViewController where I want to check when the **isSyncAutoOnGoing** is equal to **NO**. I know it is not the good way I think, and more, the value of **isSyncAutoOnGoing** is always equal to **YES**.

**FormViewController.m**

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
    id obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < [viewControllers count]; i ++)
    {
        obj = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"ViewController")])
        {
            BOOL isSyncAutoOnGoing = [[obj valueForKey:@"isSyncAutoOnGoing"] boolValue];
            if (isSyncAutoOnGoing)
            {
                do{
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
                    NSLog([[obj valueForKey:@"isSyncAutoOnGoing"] boolValue] ? @"isSyncAuto: YES" : @"isSyncAuto: NO");
                }while([[obj valueForKey:@"isSyncAutoOnGoing"] boolValue]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are certain ways to achieve this. but first you need to clear your requirement. As your code you are blocking view with  `spinner` so it will be always false when you nevigate to to other viewcontroller

Comment: Post a Notification after the image is downloaded.Observe for that notificaiton in the other VC..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the array is in AppDelegate

```
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.allNewsItems = appDelegate.allNewsItems;
    [appDelegate addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"allNewsItems"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:NULL];
```

and implement

```
  - (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"allNewsItems"]){ if ([self isBeingPresented]){
           [self.tableView reloadData]; }else{
            self.mustReloadView = YES;
        }
 } }
```